# Importing Modules — customized Modules in C

Tags: c

I am currently learning the C programming language and I'm having some issues with importing modules I created.

I created a small module to read with `fgets` and flush the buffer from stdin perfectly and I don't want to keep writing the code every single time. I just want to import this small module like I used to do in Python. I didn't knew how because I'm not using an IDE.  I'm just compiling with gcc in terminal and using a text editor. I tried to search with Google,but in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a header for your module that declares the functions in the module – and any other information that a consumer of the module needs.  You might call that header `weekly.h`, a pun on your name, but you can choose any name you like within reason.

You should create a library (shared or static — that's up to you) that contains the functions (and any global variables, if you're so gauche as to have any) defined by your module.  You might call it `libweekly.so` or `libweekly.a` — or using the extensions appropriate to your machine (`.dylib` and `.a` on macOS, for example).  The source files might or might not be `weekly.c` — if there's more than one function, you'll probably have multiple source files, so they won't all be `weekly.c`.  You should put this code (the header and the source files and their makefile) into a separate source directory.

You should install the header(s) and the library in a well-known location (e.g. `$HOME/include` for headers and `$HOME/lib` for the library — or maybe in the corresponding directories under `/usr/local`), and then ensure that the right options are used when compiling (`-I$HOME/include` for the headers) or linking (`-L$HOME/lib` and `-lweekly`).

Your source code using the module would contain:

```
#include "weekly.h"
```

and your code would be available.  With shared libraries in `$HOME/lib`, you would have to ensure that the runtime system knows where to find the library.  If you install it in `/usr/local`, that is done for you already.  If you install it in `$HOME/lib`, you have to investigate things like `/etc/ld.so.conf` or the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `DYLIB_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables, etc.

Comment: So if i did understand , besides the creating a .h file containing the Prototypes of my functions  an doing the #include in the main.c, i have to make a library(containing the the source code of my modules , the .c files ) so Gcc can find them  while compiling the Main source code like in Python is used to create a directory containing a __init__ file .

Comment: That’s what I’m recommending. An alternative you could consider in the short term is keeping the object file somewhere and explicitly link with it.  But if you start having more than a  couple such files, it is better to use a library.  It would be horrid to have to list the object files for the standard library.  Your library is not that different.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a header file (.h) with your function declarations types and extern variables. Then in the program where you want to use those functions include this .h file and and add the compiled .o file (with your functions) to the object file list. And you are done.